# Launcher activity setContentView delay

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I created a simple app with Splash screen which is shown for 1 second. Splash screen is almost red. But I noticed that when I launch my app at first for ~0.3 sec appears white screen and after that appears my Splash screen. Is it possible to remove this white screen or make it predefined red? I testes it on nexus 4 with android 5.0, and my Splash activity have quite simple implementation, and nothing can delay onCreate():

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher);
    waitTask = new WaitTask();
    waitTask.execute();
}

private class WaitTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(SPLASH_DURATION);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Do nothing
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LauncherActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

}
```

I have noticed that almost all apps show it first screen with some delay and this white screen, but in some app this screen is back. Is there any way to control it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the style of the activity and set it in the Manifest. This way, when the activity runs, it will use its pre defined style (in which you will have the background or windowBackground set to red) and within that 0.3 seconds, the windows will still be red.

Define the colour:

```
<resources>
    <color name="background">#FF0000</color>
</resources>
```

Then define the style:

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyLaunchActivityTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light"> 
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
     </style>
</resources>
```

Then set the style for the activity in the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:theme="@style/MyLaunchActivityTheme"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The ans Sam gave is perfect but to extend it - let you want to have your custom splash screen image visible for the whole time, If we apply color to the window then there will be a switch from color to the actual slash screen. The ans which i propose dont require setContentView but only manage splash screen through theme.

We can't set the theme in java as in my case the control came to onCreate of my splash activity very late. Till that time black screen keep visible.

This gave me clue that window has to be managed from theme which we specify in manifest.

There is the manifest i have:

```
<activity
        android:name=".main.activities.SplashScreen"
        android:theme="@style/Splash"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Now The theme i created is as follows:

```
<style name="Splash" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/green_09</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green_09</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Splash in the drawable resource which contains a bitmap resource, I have to tweak a bit to make it look perfect not stretched and in center:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:antialias="true"
    android:dither="true"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:src="@drawable/splash_screen" />
```